# Create an or-constraint over a list of Bools

Tags: python, z3, z3py

I am playing with Z3 in Python to generate solutions for a dissolution puzzle. I have no prior experience with SAT/SMT solvers or Z3 and even my Python is still at pidgin-level. So please be gentle.

In my approach I have two lists xs and ys of Bools. I know from other constraints that in each of the two lists at most one of the entries is True and all others are False. Either zero or one True entry per list.

I want to add a constraint that compares the two lists on wether they both have a True entry or are both all-False.

So I want something like `or(all_the_xs)==or(all_the_ys)`. I have a feeling this should be pretty native to Z3 but I can't figure out how to state it.

I managed to do it by comparing the count of True-values using `z3.Sum([z3.If(x,1,0) for x in xs])` but this does take it out of the realm of simple Booleans. It also feels inelegant and less efficient as possible.

Here is a representative self-contained example of my bodged code using `Sum()`:

```
import z3

solver = z3.Solver()

xs = [ z3.Bool("x_{i}".format(i=i)) for i in range(0,10) ]
ys = [ z3.Bool("y_{i}".format(i=i)) for i in range(0,10) ]

xsum = z3.Sum([z3.If(x,1,0) for x in xs])
ysum = z3.Sum([z3.If(x,1,0) for x in ys])

solver.add(xsum == ysum)

solver.check()
print(solver.model())
```

Can you help me restating this in a prettier and more Z3-friendly form? Or assure me it's fine as it is?

Thank you for reading and thinking,
Marian

Comment: Basic Python: `any(all_the_xes) == any(all_the_ys)`

Comment: Well, if you already know that only one Boolean variable can be true at any given time, then there is no need to count the variables at all. Simply write `or(x_0, ..., x_N) <=> or(y_0, ...., y_M)`, where  `<=>` is double implication, with the appropriate `z3py` syntax.

Comment: Thank you triplee. Sorry for not being clear enough.

`solver.add(any(xs) == any(ys))`

"Symbolic expressions cannot be cast to concrete Boolean values."

These are z3 Bool variables for wich the solver is asked to find a valid combination that satisfies all the constraints. Not a list of Python booleans with specific values.

Comment: Thank you Patrick. Figuring out the appropriate z3py syntax is precisely my problem :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're in luck! z3py comes with `Or`, which takes a list of booleans:

```py
import z3

solver = z3.Solver()

xs = [ z3.Bool("x_{i}".format(i=i)) for i in range(0,10) ]
ys = [ z3.Bool("y_{i}".format(i=i)) for i in range(0,10) ]

solver.add(z3.Or(xs) == z3.Or(ys))

solver.check()
print(solver.model())
```

This prints:

```
[x_0 = False,
 x_1 = False,
 x_2 = False,
 x_3 = False,
 x_4 = False,
 x_5 = False,
 x_6 = False,
 x_7 = False,
 x_8 = False,
 x_9 = False,
 y_0 = False,
 y_1 = False,
 y_2 = False,
 y_3 = False,
 y_4 = False,
 y_5 = False,
 y_6 = False,
 y_7 = False,
 y_8 = False,
 y_9 = False]
```

Not the most interesting model, but I believe this is precisely what you are looking for!

Comment: I think he wants an *if and only if* among the two *or*. Could you please double-check your answer?

Comment: Oh so easy! It never occured to me to just do Or over a list. I need to do way more Python before this sinks in.

Thank you!